# Can you discretize a continuous ODE using time dependent step size $\epsilon(k)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, soft-question, numerical-methods, mathematical-modeling, discrete-optimization

Suppose I am given a first order ode of the type

$$\dot x(t) = f(x(t))$$

Then let $t = k$, $k \in \mathbb{N}$

> Is it possible to discretize ("Forward Euler") using a
>   time dependent step size $\epsilon(k)$

$$\dot x \cong \dfrac{x(k+1) - x(k)}{\epsilon(k)}$$

$$\implies x(k+1) = x(k) + \epsilon(k)f(x(k))$$

---

I am asking because I am looking at [some discretization of an ODE](http://fausto.dynamic.ucsd.edu/sonia/papers/data/2016_EJR-SM-auto.pdf) (pg 5) where $\epsilon(k)$ is used as the discretizing time step. I have only seen the time step taken as a constant i.e. $\epsilon(k) = \epsilon, \forall k$, where $\epsilon$ is small.

Any additional examples will help.

Comment: Yes it is possible to do, as long as you keep track of time points you are at. If steps would be constant that would not be necessary as then time should be a linear space.

Comment: As long as you use a smooth variation for the time step your perturbation is little and you can assume all the formulas derived for constant time step are still valid. If the time step varies too fast you can easily introduce oscillations in the solution.

Comment: @N74 Hi can you provide a reference or do you know if there are examples for using time varying time step?

Comment: I once used a paper as a reference to use a time varying time step, but many years passed by and I don't know how to find it. Anyway I remember it assumed a slowly varying time step and approximated it with a first order differntial, then this differential was assumed smaller than the function delta and was so cancelled from the equations.

Comment: Any one-step integrator (e.g. RK family) may work with variable timestep. Even multistep methods (in Nordsieck vector formulation) are not restricted to constant timestep

Comment: @uranix Hi can you provide some examples and what do you mean one-step integrator? You mean a first order ODE?